# Attach Javascript to Certain Form Field Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Autocomplete Script that works great but i am adding it to a page with MULTIPLE FORMS and now it wont work.

here is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#zipsearch').autocomplete({source:'suggest_zip.php', minLength:2});
    });

</script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" /> 
<style type="text/css"><!--

        /* style the auto-complete response */
        li.ui-menu-item { font-size:12px !important; }

--></style>
```

and the form With Field is:

```
<form action="<?php echo $GLOBALS["webroot"]; ?>/index.php?action=<?php echo $GLOBALS["RFA"];?>" method="post" name="postForm1">

<input name="LocationID" type="text" class="span10" id="zipsearch">
```

I have tried:

```
jQuery(document).postForm1.ready(function(){
    $('#zipsearch').postForm1.autocomplete({source:'suggest_zip.php', minLength:2});
});
```

this was the TEST Form that is in the same folder as the page i am currently working on... everything works on this test page

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>test jquery autocomplete</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('#zipsearch').autocomplete({source:'suggest_zip.php', minLength:2});
        });

    </script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" /> 
    <style type="text/css"><!--

            /* style the auto-complete response */
            li.ui-menu-item { font-size:12px !important; }

    --></style> 
</head> 

<body> 

<form onsubmit="return false;"> 
    Enter a City:
    <input id="zipsearch" type="text" /> 
</form> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using the same ID for multiple input fields? If so, you shouldn't be. ID's should be unique.

Comment: Ok. Why are trying to wait for the form to be ready? You should add class to all of your autocomplete fields, and use that class in the selector. That way jQuery UI will instantiate the plugin on each field.

Comment: only have one field on this page for this at moment will be adding another once i get one to work

Comment: I see that you are using a custom roll of the jQuery UI, did you forget to include the autocomplete widget?

Comment: It works perfectly on the sample test page in same directory

Comment: http://www.digihaul.info/pages/jquery_autocomplete.html test page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to all of the fields you want an autocomplete on:

```
<input name="LocationID" type="text" class="span10 autocomplete" id="zipsearch">
<input type="text" class="span10 autocomplete">
<input type="text" class="span10 autocomplete">
```

Then, change your selector:

```
$(function() {
    $('.autocomplete').autocomplete({source:'suggest_zip.php', minLength:2});
});
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to JS... not even sure where the consol is?

Comment: http://www.digihaul.info/pages/jquery_autocomplete.html   is a test link... enter a city name

Comment: Uh, it is working for me. I typed in "atla" and got a dropdown showing cities.

Comment: uncaught object has no method

Answer (score 1):

PostForm1 is written false, 
your form is named postForm1 with a small p ;-)

For one ID use it like this, it takes no mather in what form your id is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
        $("#zipsearch").autocomplete({source:'suggest_zip.php',minLength:2});
        });
```

Comment: Try $("#zipsearch").autocomplete({source:'suggest_zip.php',minLength:2});

Comment: This will apply autocomplete only on this field, no mather in what form it is.

Comment: Other thing that could be wrong is your php source; is the suggest_zip.php available for your code?

Comment: i dont even get the spinner in the form field... it has something to do with the field not linking to the JS.

Comment: So when the spinners dont work... are your jquery documents in the right folder ( i mean the path to the documents)

Comment: yes i will include a sample test page in same folder as this page i am working with

Comment: uncaught object has no method

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Guys it was Me... I didnt put the files in the main directory... where my index.php control file resides

thanks for all the help